# How to import own template to TYPO3

Tags: bootstrap-4, typo3

We intend to do the basic part of our website using:

https://www.templatemonster.com/intense-multipurpose-html-template.html

It is website tools, templates based on Bootstrap. In the near future there will be an upgrade to Bootstrap 4.x

We are also considering as basic platform of our site to be TYPO3 - e.g. possibility of interaction in some places.

How is the best method to transfer a customized template or a ready to use website to Typo3? At what stage is it best done?

We want to keep of course the navigation, footer - customized by us in the template and not in TYPO3.

What can you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can start your work with the TYPO3 bootstrap package, see https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/bootstrap_package/ and https://www.bootstrap-package.com/de/. The package is actively maintained by Benji Kott. He is working hard to further improve this package.

There is also a second one around but I do not know it: https://t3bootstrap.de/en/typo3-bootstrap-template/

You can port your custom theme into one of the bootstrap packages. The mentioned TYPO3 packages do a lot of optimizations you don't have to think about. But you need a basic knowledge of TYPO3.

Answer (score 0):

Template, template and template.
You need to differ what is meant with the word.
Especially TYPO3 has multiple meanings for this word.

1. the typoscript configuration (it is stored in template records in the database, having two parts: `constants` and `setup`. In newer times the content is outsourced to files which can be versioned.
2. a piece of html-markup which contains placeholders for content.
   Here TYPO3 knows at least two different versions:

   1. "Marker templates" is the old way where you have markers like `###MYMARKER###` which either came as braces, where the `subpart` is replaced or just the marker is replaced with content
   2. `Fluid templates` the modern way, where you have `viewhelper` and `variables`to control the output.

   these templates are used for parts of the resulting page, e.g. you have templates to show news records, other templates for menus and others for all kind of content.
3. HTML and CSS as an example for a design.

What you get from templatemonster is version 3. this needs adaption to be usable as version 2 in TYPO3. Therefore you need to break it down to pieces for each kind of content: build the (fluid-)templates for a slider, the (fluid-)templates for the menu, the (fluid-)templates for news, menus, footer, ...

As this template is based on bootstrap maybe you an use the default (version 2) templates of TYPO3 and extensions as they already have the correct HTML markup and only the CSS is neccessary to give the desired design (version 3 template)